# IBM Worklight - How to customize an app after creating its .api/.apk?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I wish to distribute my enterprise Worklight application to many different clients.

Basically what I want to do is give my customer the .ipa and .apk files of the Worklight app so that they may upload them onto their own Application Center. The problem is that each application needs to be slightly different in that there are different URLs they must refer to as well as some other properties such as text.

I was wondering if there's a way to have my ipa/apk read from a properties that my client could change on their own without having to rebuild the ipa/apk?

EDIT for clarification:

The application I'm referring to is NOT the Application Center app, it is an application I've built using Worklight that I would like to distribute using the Application Center. I will be selling my application to entire companies rather than single users. Once the company has the application, their employees will need to download it somehow (using the Application Center I'm hoping).

Right now I'm trying to figure out exactly how I will distribute my application to my clients. My application calls services of another application hosted on another server (aka the "URL" I was referring to before, it is NOT the Worklight URL). The problem is this URL will be different per client and as far as I know right now in order to change this URL per client, I must recompile the ipa/apk for each client. This is what I'd like to avoid. If possible I would like to distribute the same ipa/apk to each client and have them change some sort of parameter somewhere to set the correct URL for their environment. It's also important to note this URL does not go through an adapter, and lives directly in the client.

Comment: If you are referring to the Worklight Server URL, end users can change the Worklight server URL in Android and iOS using the Settings screen for the app.

Comment: Trying to answer this question, I feel it is really LACKING in that the scenario is really not clear enough; please edit with a specific example of what you'd like to achieve. Right now it's not clear at all. What is this "URL"? The server URL? just some any url in the content of the app? are you actually referring to the different environments in the app? Please be clearer.

Comment: Also are you talking about things to change in the worklight app or appcenter app? because you mention appcenter, but the question it self is talking about the worklight app, and there is no connection between the two.

Comment: Sorry I've edited the question and tried to clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO what you are asking for is not possible, be it with a regular native app or a Worklight hybrid app (that is really a web app but enclosed in a native "shell").

Once you produce the .ipa or .apk file, it is closed and cannot (unless cracked) be opened to make changes (that would be a security breach). Using a "properties file" next to the app is obviously not possible either.

You will need to create a custom .ipa/.apk for each customer.

Comment: I wonder how other people solve this problem then? Basically I'm not allowed to give the source code to the operations team (who sets up the client's environement) and they have to be able to setup a client environment that points to the correct URL. Do you know a way to do this properly?

Comment: Sorry, no. Can you elaborate on the second topic I mentioned in my answer?

Comment: This is correct, currently our app even though developed in Worklight works fine when the Worklight Server is off, so technically we aren't using Worklight Server.