# IBM Worklight - Where to find the server URL while in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ibm-mobilefirst

Is there a way where I can change my Worklight Server URL after building an environment?

For example: I'm supposed to change my Worklight Server URL in Visual Studio directly.
Can you help me locate the file wherein I can achieve this ?

Comment: Explain the need for this requirement.

Comment: Idan, Let's say I'm distributing the WP8 version of my App to a specific Geography and my android / iOS version to a different geographical space being handled by its respective Worklight  Servers. In this case I will be releasing a common package and later allow the Team to customize the endpoints. Let me know if you feel I can go wrong in this approach

Comment: You did not mention your Worklight version, but in Worklight 6.0.0.x and 6.1.0.0 there is the possibility to build the project for a remote server, meaning that you will generate a .wlapp that is configured to connect to a different server as well as set the appropriate settings in the native folder. Read more about this in the IBM Worklight Information Center.

Comment: Hi Idan, Now I'm following the said approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  should not change the Worklight Server URL post build.
Read why:

- [IBM Worklight - How to change the url of the worklight server dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20883345/ibm-worklight-how-to-change-the-url-of-the-worklight-server-dynamically)
- [Worklight Apps pointing to different Worklight Servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20151784/worklight-apps-pointing-to-different-worklight-servers)
- [IBM Worklight - How to customize an app after creating its .api/.apk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081467/ibm-worklight-how-to-customize-an-app-after-creating-its-api-apk)

In any case, in the Windows 8 or Windows Phone 8 environment while the generated project is opened in Visual Studio, the Worklight Server URL is located inside the generated HTML file, which can be found in the `native\www\default` folder.

This differs from other environments where the Worklight Server URL will be found in a separate properties file, for example iOS (worklight.plist) or Android (wlclient.properties).

---

Addendum based on your comments: read the following IBM Worklight Information Center topics to understand how to build your project for deployment to remote Worklight Servers. In your case you will need to repeat this step for each of your different customer environments, perhaps even use ant scripts to do this. Search the Information Center.

- [Deploying an application from development to a test or production environment](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/t_transporting_the_app.html)

Comment: Got that Idan !!! And surprisingly changing the Server URL works ( Although I understand it is not the right way of doing it ) Guess I can trick this atleast till development phase